# Using PHP and mysql I want to allow a user to select result from array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of academic references which are part of a common bank which all users are able to see.  I want to give the user the option to choose which one of the references they want to add to their own list and output on a separate page.

I aim to use a unique reference ID which is then linked to a separate user table and when they go to their personal page it outputs the references which they have chosen.

What I have tried to do so far is have a button next to all of the references which have been output and the button is linked to a form which then takes the user to a new page which performs the INSERT INTO statement to add the reference ID along side their student ID as a composite key.

What I have is as follows (removed a few fields to simplify):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM references")or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Reference ID</td>";
echo "<td>Author</td>";
echo "<td>Save</td>";
echo "</tr>";
 while($refer = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 
 { 

 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td><form name='addreference' method='post' action='saveref.php'><input type='text' name='referenceid' readonly='readonly' id='refid' value='".$refer['refid'] . "'/></td> ";
 echo "<td>".$refer['author'] . "</td> ";  
 echo "<td><center><input type='submit' name='addref' value='Add'></center></td>";
```

The correct Reference IDs output on this screen but when I do var_dump($_POST) on saveref.php the Reference ID posted is always that of the last one in the array regardless of which button is clicked on the list of references.  What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Please do not continue using mysql_-class functions. Either use mysqli_, MYSQLI::, or PDO. See php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

As noted in the comments, you should use mysqli instead of mysql, as mysql is deprecated.

Here's a rewrite to your form that will allow you to post an array of references to saveref.php.  I included a lot of improvements, including double-quotes on your HTML attributes (a W3 recommendation), added thead and tbody to your table, and put your references in checkboxes with a single button at the bottom.

```
<form name="addreference" method="post" action="saveref.php">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Reference ID</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Save</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM references";
$results = mysql_query($sql)
    or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($refer = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 
    echo <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td>{$refer['refid']}</td>
            <td>{$refer['author']}</td>  
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="references[]" value="{$refer['refid']}"/></td>
        </tr>
HTML;
}
?>
<button type="submit" name="addref">Add Selected</button>
</form>
```

Your `saveref.php` file would then look like this:

```
<?php
$student_id = 1; // This value would get set elsewhere, I presume?
$references = !empty($_POST['references']) ? (array) $_POST['references'] : array();
$cnt = count($references);
if ($cnt) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $references[$i] = "(" . ((int) $student_id) . ", " . ((int) $references[$i]) . ")";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO references (student_id, reference_id) VALUES ";
    $sql .= implode(", ", $references);
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Edited the `INSERT` query for added performance.  This new query will insert multiple records in a single query.

Comment: Looking much better now thanks but now when opening saveref.php I am getting an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/addref.php

This is happening on this line:

    $references = (!empty($_POST['references']) ? (array) $_POST['references'] : array();

and also 
            $references[$i] = "(" . ((int) $student_id . ", " . ((int) $references[$i]) . ")";

Comment: @drmscp - I fixed both those bugs.  The first line had an extra ( and the other had a missing )

Comment: no errors now however when opening saveref.php a blank page opens and nothing updated on the table.  Will try and sort it.  Really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Well, it's just a "save" action.  You should consider having that redirect to some other page to display updates.

Comment: The `saveref.php` page creates a query like this: `INSERT INTO references (student_id, reference_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4);` - if your table is not named `references`, or if the columns are named something other than `student_id` or `reference_id`, you'll have to update the script to properly reference the names of your DB objects.  Also, you should update it so that it sets `$student_id` appropriately